# rspec testing strong params and building a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am attempting to write a model test, like so:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Five9List do
  before :each do
    @five9_list = Five9List.new(name: 'test_list', size: '100')
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "takes two parameters and returns a Five9List object" do
      @five9_list.should be_an_instance_of Five9List
    end
  end

  describe "#name" do
    it "returns the correct name" do
      @five9_list.name.should eql "test_list"
    end
  end
  describe "#size" do
    it "returns the correct size" do
      @five9_list.size.should eql 100
    end
  end
end
```

Currently, this succeeds and works fine. That's because my model is using attr_accessible, like so:

```
class Five9List < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :size

end
```

If I want to get rid of `attr_accessible` and follow the rails 4 convention of using `strong_params`, how would I write that to where my `rspec` test would still succeed?

Adding this in my controller:

```
private
  def five9_list_params
    params.require(:five9_list).permit(:name, :size)
  end
```

And removing attr_accessible does not work.

## EDIT

Here is the error I receive from `rspec .`:

```
Failures:

  1) Five9List#name returns the correct name
     Failure/Error: @five9_list.name.should eql "test_list"

       expected: "test_list"
            got: nil

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/models/five9_list_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Five9List#size returns the correct size
     Failure/Error: @five9_list.size.should eql 100

       expected: 100
            got: nil

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/models/five9_list_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03303 seconds
4 examples, 2 failures, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/five9_list_spec.rb:15 # Five9List#name returns the correct name
rspec ./spec/models/five9_list_spec.rb:21 # Five9List#size returns the correct size

Randomized with seed 20608
```

Comment: u are requiring wrong param (:name) check your params properly and pass it inside require()...here i think it should be require(:five9_list).....if u are using rails default REST routes

Comment: I fixed the above, and I am using default REST routes. Still no luck though.

Comment: Your test doesn't involve any controller code, so nothing in your controller matters and your routes don't matter either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your spec. I can only guess that you're not running Rails 4 or you've installed the ProtectedAttributes gem.

Comment: I do have the appropriate columns in my DB. Still no dice.

Comment: Nailed it. I had the ProtectedAttributes gem installed, I was thinking that only added functionality - not hindered the strong_params functionality. Thanks for the tip!